# When does $f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ imply that $f(t_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for a sequence $t_n \to 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $F\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function on a Hilbert space. When does the existence of the limit
$$F(t) \to 0 \text{ as $t \to 0$}$$
imply that, for a sequence $t_n \to 0$,
$$F(t_n) \to 0 \text{ as $n \to \infty$}?$$

How can I show this?

Comment: Just Definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always.

The existence of the first limit can be written as:

> For every $\epsilon$, there exists some $\delta$ such that if $\|t\|<\delta$, then $|f(t)|<\epsilon$

---

in the second case, we assume that the following is true:

> For every $\epsilon$, there exists some $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $\|t_n\| < \epsilon$

and we are asking if the following is true:

> For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $|F(t_n)| < \epsilon$.

---

You can probably already see that the definitions are very similar. So similar, in fact, that the proof should probably just follow the definitions. So, start with the old standard "Let $\epsilon > 0$", and see where that takes you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(t) \to 0 \text{ as $t \to 0$}$. This means:

for every $\epsilon >0$ there is $ \delta >0$ such that $t \in X$ and $||t||< \delta$ imply that $|F(x)|< \epsilon$.

Now let $(t_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ such that $t_n \to 0$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $ \delta $ as above. Then there is $N$ such that $||t_n||< \delta$ for all $n>N$.

Hence $|F(t_n)|< \epsilon$ for all $n>N$. This gives $ F(t_n) \to 0 \text{ as $n \to \infty$}$